# How to using Scanner to take out odd number lines and place them in order?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How to using Scanner to take out odd number lines and place them in order?

The problem is that I have a text file and looks like this :

```
case0:
a1:
    0
a2:
    0
a3:
    0
a4:
    0
a5:
    0
a6:
    0
a7:
    1
a8:
    0
a9:
    0
```

I need to let the output to be like :

```
caseNumber :0
case content :000000100
```

How to do it ?

Here is a version ive write so far , you may like to add some on that :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileScanner {

    File f = new File("test.txt");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileScanner fs = new FileScanner();

        fs.readfile();

    }

    public void readfile() {

        try {

            // create a new scanner with the specified String Object
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);

            int lineCount = 0;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                lineCount++;
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                // System.out.println("Line :" + line);
                String line1 = line.trim();
                // System.out.println(line1);

                for (lineCount = 0; lineCount<19; lineCount++) {



                    line1 = line1.substring(line1.lastIndexOf("e") + 1);
                    // System.out.println("what is here :"+line1);
                    line1 = line1.substring(0, line1.lastIndexOf(":"));


                    int caseNum = Integer.parseInt(line1);
                    System.out.println("caseNumber :" + caseNum);





                };

                // System.out.println(""+line1);
                // int caseNumber = Integer.parseInt(line1);
                // System.out.println("caseNumber :" + caseNumber);
            }

            System.out.println("line count" + lineCount);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        }
        // find the next token and print it
        // System.out.println("" + scanner.next());

        // find the next token and print it
        // System.out.println("" + scanner.next());

        // close the scanner
    }
}
```

---

Contious of last question ..
RIght , i got  the output like this :

```
Case Number: -1
Case Contents: 000000100
Line Count: 4085
```

which i think got a little bit wrong on the case number .

Then i got 215 sets of cases (in the same file and same format with the first set of data),and i need to make the output like :

```
Case Number: 0
Case Contents: 000000100

Case Number: 1
Case Contents: 000000101

Case Number: 2
Case Contents: 000010101 
.
.
.(showing all the cases)
Line Count: 4085
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a method to your class that determines if a String is numeric:

```
private boolean isNumeric(String number)
{
    try
    {
        Integer.parseInt(number);
        return true;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The way this method works is that we attempt to parse the String as an int, and if that fails, because we are using a try/catch statement, we can prevent the program from throwing an error and instead just `return false;`. If it doesn't fail, it will continue on to the `return true;`

Now that we have a way of determining what is an isn't a number, we can rework the `while` loop to take advantage of the new method:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);

int lineCount = 0;
int caseNumber = -1;
String contents = "";
while(scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    lineCount++;
    String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
    if(lineCount == 1)
    {
        if(line.startsWith("case"))
        {
            String subStr = line.substring(line.indexOf("e") + 1,
                line.indexOf(":"));
            if(isNumeric(subStr))
                caseNumber = Integer.parseInt(subStr);
        }
    }
    else if(isNumeric(line))
        contents += line;
}

scanner.close();

System.out.println("Case Number: " + caseNumber);
System.out.println("Case Contents: " + contents);
System.out.println("Line Count: " + lineCount);
```

Here is what I changed: First, I added a new `int caseNumber` to represent the case number. Then I added a new `String contents` to represent the contents of the case. Next, I changed:

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
```

to

```
String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
```

and got rid of the other `String line1 = line.trim();` because there is no reason to create two new variables when we can do both operations on just one.

Next I added an if-statement to see if we are on the first line so we can determine the case number. If the line starts with `"case"` then we take the substring from `e` to `:`, represented as `subStr`, to get the case number. Run `subStr` through our `isNumeric` method, and we can determine if the case number can be parsed as an int. If that returns true, we set `caseNumber` equal to `Integer.parseInt(subStr)` which will turn the String into an int.

Then I added an else-statement to handle all the lines after the first line. For each of these lines, all we have to do is determine if the line is a number using `isNumeric`. If it is numeric, we append it to the end of `contents` using the `+=` operator. If it isn't, we skip over it.

Lastly, I made sure to **close the scanner** by executing `scanner.close()` so that we don't have a resource leak.

And there you go! I hope you can understand and learn from all the changes made. Here is the output of this program:

```
Case Number: 0
Case Contents: 000000100
Line Count: 19
```

---

To answer your follow-up question:

Here is the while loop that will allow you to print out multiple cases and their contents:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);

int lineCount = 0;
int caseNumber = -1;
String contents = "";
while(scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    lineCount++;
    String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
    if(line.startsWith("case"))
    {
        if(!contents.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Case Number: " + caseNumber);
            System.out.println("Case Contents: " + contents);
            caseNumber = -1;
            contents = "";
        }
        String subStr = line.substring(line.indexOf("e") + 1,
                line.indexOf(":"));
        if(isNumeric(subStr))
            caseNumber = Integer.parseInt(subStr);
    }
    else if(isNumeric(line))
        contents += line;
}

scanner.close();

System.out.println("Case Number: " + caseNumber);
System.out.println("Case Contents: " + contents);
System.out.println("Line Count: " + lineCount);
```

Here is what I changed from the previous answer to make it work:

First I removed the if-statement that checks if the lineCount == 1, and attached the else-statement to the end of the second if-statement that checks if the line begins with "case".

So in other words, this:

```
if(lineCount == 1)
{
    if(line.startsWith("case"))
    {
        ...
    }
}
else if(isNumeric(line))
    ...
```

Became this:

```
if(line.startsWith("case"))
{
    ...
}
else if(isNumeric(line))
    ...
```

Next, I added a new if-statement within the `if(line.startsWith("case"))` statement that checks if we are on a new case or not. Basically what it does is check if the `contents` string is empty. If it is, we are on case `0`. If it isn't, we are on a case greater than `0`. If the statement is true, we print out the case number and contents, then reset the values of the two variables so they can be used again:

```
if(!contents.isEmpty())
{
    System.out.println("Case Number: " + caseNumber);
    System.out.println("Case Contents: " + contents);
    caseNumber = -1;
    contents = "";
}
```

And that's it! Really!

Here is the output:

```
Case Number: 0
Case Contents: 000000100
Case Number: 1
Case Contents: 101001001
Line Count: 38
```

Enjoy!

Comment: OMG ! thank you so much ! Then if i got quite a big number of sets of this case number and i want to shown like : Case Number: 0
Case Contents: 000000100
Case Number: 1
Case Contents: 000000101
Line Count: 38  and so on ... how to do that ?

Comment: @Yolk No problem! Make sure to accept my answer if it works for you. Your next question is a bit more complicated, so try getting this working, and once you get it, post another question on Stack Overflow and I will make a separate answer.

Comment: I  can only post once every 90 minutes , ive accept your answer =) RIght , i got the output like this :
Case Number: -1
Case Contents: 000000100
Line Count: 4085

which i think got a little bit wrong on the case number .

Then i got 215 sets of cases (in the same file and same format with the first set of data),and i need to make the output like :
Case Number: 0
Case Contents: 000000100

Case Number: 1
Case Contents: 000000101

Case Number: 2
Case Contents: 000010101 
.
.
.(showing all the cases)
Line Count: 4085

Comment: Can you post your while loop so I can see why case number might be -1?

Comment: I didnt make any changes from yours . here is it :while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    lineCount++;
    String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
    if (lineCount == 1) {
     if (line.startsWith("case")) {
      String subStr = line.substring(line.indexOf("e") + 1,
        line.indexOf(":"));
      if (isNumeric(subStr))
       caseNumber = Integer.parseInt(subStr);
     }
    } else if (isNumeric(line))
     contents += line;
   }

Comment: I found why case number is 1 .I replaced String subStr = line.substring(line.indexOf("e") + 1,
line.indexOf(":")); with line = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf("e") + 1);
         
      line = line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(":"));   then it works fine .

Comment: @Yolk good job! Take a look at my edit above for your second question.

Answer (score 3):

you can readfile line by line:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
```

after you can check line string if it is numeric with a boolean function

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
{  
  try  
  {  
    double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
  }  
  catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
  {  
    return false;  
  }  
  return true;  
}
```

OR you can read file and keep a counter for lines OR you can have a flag that change every time  OR you can use str.contains(":"); while you reading the file and understand with this way that there is not a content you want.

this is one posible solution:

```
package test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
/**
 *
 * @author Alex
 */
public class encrypt {



public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
{  
    str.contains(str);
  try  
  {  
    double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
  }  
  catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
  {  
    return false;  
  }  
  return true;  
}
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here

        String mycase="caseNumber :", case_cont="case content :";


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(line);
            if(line.contains("case"))
            {
                mycase=mycase+line.replace("case", "").replace(":", "");
            }
            else if(isNumeric(line)==true)
            {
                case_cont=case_cont+line.replaceAll("\\s+","");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(mycase);
        System.out.println(case_cont);
    }
}
```

Comment: A great method to do it as well ! Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class FileScanner {

    File f = new File("test.txt");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileScanner fs = new FileScanner();

        fs.readfile();

    }

    public void readfile() {

        try {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            List<String>strings = new ArrayList<String>();
            StringTokenizer st ;
            int lineCount = 0;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                lineCount++;
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                line = line.trim();
                builder.append(line +" "); //better then String s+= line
            }
            scanner.close();
            st = new StringTokenizer(builder.toString()," ");
            builder = new StringBuilder();
            while(st.hasMoreElements()){
                String s = st.nextElement().toString();
                if(s.contains("a")&&s.contains(":")&&!s.contains("case")){
                    continue;
                }
                else if(s.contains("case")){
                    builder.append(":"+s);
                }
                else{
                    builder.append(s);
                }
            }
            st = new StringTokenizer(builder.toString(),":");
            while(st.hasMoreElements()){
                strings.add(st.nextElement().toString());

            }
            for(int i=0;i<strings.size()-1;i++){
                if(strings.get(i).contains("case")){
                    System.out.println("Case Number: " + strings.get(i));
                    if(i+1 <strings.size()){
                        System.out.println("Case Contents: " + strings.get(i+1));
                    }

                }
            }
            System.out.println("line count : " + lineCount);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thats cool ! But if i need separate array , how to deal with it ? I need a CaseNumStrings array which only contain casenumbers and a CaseContStrings array which only contain casecontents. Then i can do something like System.out.println("40th case number is :" + CaseNumStrings[40]);
   System.out.println("40th case content is :" + CaseNumStrings[40]);

Answer (score 2):

I make some modification to let you choose what case do you want print

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class FileScanner {

    File f = new File("test.txt");
    List<String>cases = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String>contents = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String>strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileScanner fs = new FileScanner();

        fs.readfile();
        for(int i = 0; i<fs.getCases().size();i++){
            System.out.println("case number  is : "+ fs.getCase(i));
            System.out.println("case content is : "+fs.getContent(i) );

        }
    }

    public void readfile() {

        try {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            StringTokenizer st ;
            int lineCount = 0;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                lineCount++;
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                line = line.trim();
                builder.append(line +" "); //better then String s+= line
            }
            scanner.close();
            st = new StringTokenizer(builder.toString()," ");
            builder = new StringBuilder();
            while(st.hasMoreElements()){
                String s = st.nextElement().toString();
                if(s.contains("a")&&s.contains(":")&&!s.contains("case")){
                    continue;
                }
                else if(s.contains("case")){
                    builder.append(":"+s);
                }
                else{
                    builder.append(s);
                }
            }
            st = new StringTokenizer(builder.toString(),":");
            while(st.hasMoreElements()){
                strings.add(st.nextElement().toString());

            }

            for(int i=0;i<strings.size();i++){
                if(strings.get(i).contains("case")){
                    cases.add(strings.get(i));
                }
                else{
                    contents.add(strings.get(i));
                }
            }
            System.out.println("line count : " + lineCount);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        }

    }


    public String getCase(int index) {
        if(!cases.isEmpty() &&index <cases.size()){
            return cases.get(index);
        }
        return "NaN";
    }


    public String getContent(int index) {
        if(!contents.isEmpty() &&index <contents.size()){
            return contents.get(index);
        }
        return "NaN";
    }


    public List<String> getCases() {
        return cases;
    }


    public void setCases(List<String> cases) {
        this.cases = cases;
    }


    public List<String> getContents() {
        return contents;
    }


    public void setContents(List<String> contents) {
        this.contents = contents;
    }

}
```